# Use custom conventions when persisting Rebus sagas in MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, rebus

When I store my domain in MongoDB, I´m using a custom convention (as stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996399/storing-enums-as-strings-in-mongodb/18874502#18874502)) in order to persist my enums as they string representation, as we found it easier when debugging.

I would like to do the same when using MongoDB as my saga storage in Rebus. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my bad... The conventions are defined globally using the ConventionsRegistry

```
var conventions = new ConventionPack();
conventions.Add(new EnumSerializationConvention(BsonType.String));
ConventionRegistry.Register("Saga conventions", conventions, x => true);
```

The key is the third parameter of the Register method, that acts as a filter to select what classes are affected by the convention (in my case I was filtering by the namespace, and that was the reason that the saga data was not beign persisted correctly).