# C#: How to store enum value as lowercase string in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, enums

I'm trying to save an enum value as lowercase or with my custom representation on MongoDB using the C# driver. I already figured out how to save the enum value as string on the database, doing something like this

```
class MyClass
{
   ...
   [BsonRepresentation(representation: BsonType.String)]
   public MyEnum EnumValue { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

and the enum class is like this

```
[JsonConverter(converterType: typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
enum MyEnum 
{
   [EnumMember(Value = "first_value")]
   FirstValue,
   [EnumMember(Value = "second_value")]
   SecondValue
}
```

But on MongoDB the enum value is stored as it is in the enum class (not like what is specified in the EnumMember attribute). How can I tell MongoDB to store the enum value lowercase or with the EnumMember value?

Comment: check this link that will help you [MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996399/storing-enums-as-strings-in-mongodb) sorry

Comment: Ehm.... you linked my same question 

Comment: check this [link](https://code-examples.net/en/q/6ac1af)

Comment: Thanks, a custom serializer worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own Serializer:

```
internal class LowerCaseEnumSerializer<T> : SerializerBase<T>
    where T : struct
{
    public override T Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var enumValue = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(context.Reader.ReadString());

        return Enum.Parse<T>(enumValue);
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, T value)
    {
        context.Writer.WriteString(value.ToString()?.ToLowerInvariant());
    }
}
```

And then use it like attribute:

```
[BsonSerializer(typeof(LowerCaseEnumSerializer<MyEnum>))]
public MyEnum EnumValue { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).